# Como adicionar um diretório vazio em um repositório remoto git?

Tags: git

Possuo uma aplicação PHP que precisa fazer upload de fotos para um diretório remoto, mas esse diretório precisa ser criado anteriormente no repositório para que possa ser feito o upload desses arquivos.

Mas quando envio este diretório vazio, o repositório não reconhece.

Como posso fazer para enviar um diretório vazio para o repositório remoto git?

Comment: Talvez seja importante, mas, só por curiosidade, por que você iria querer versionar um diretório vazio?

Comment: Muito certo. Eu adicionado um exemplo para ajudar a entender. Obrigado!

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/256998/64969

Answer (score 6):

Git não permite ter diretórios vazio. Mas você pode gerar um arquivo oculto dentro do diretório para fazer upload desse diretório.

A maioria das pessoas fazem esse procedimento gerando um arquivo chamado **.gitignore**

Desta forma, se o diretório **data** estiver vazio, você ainda sim pode fazer o upload do diretório, com a seguinte linha de comando:

```
touch data/.gitignore
```

Depois efetuando o comando `git commit -a` seu repositório remoto será atualizado com o arquivo oculto dentro do diretório desejado.

Comment: Fique claro que o arquivo `.gitignore` tem uma função especial, que é definir quais arquivos do diretório (ou descendentes) devem ser ignorados no repositório. E geralmente não se recomenda ter vários `.gitignore` num mesmo projeto, embora seja possível.

Answer (score 5):

O arquivo `.gitkeep`, que pode ser usado no seu projeto quando, por vários motivos diferentes você deseja criar um diretório vazio e commita-lo em determinado ponto do desenvolvimento. Ex: Quando você criar um diretório para guardar arquivos como fotos, PDFs e por aí vai…

O arquivo `.gitkeep` é apenas uma convenção entre desenvolvedores, não havendo nenhuma menção sobre este (até o presente momento) no site [oficial do Git](https://git-scm.com/), mas como é um padrão entre desenvolvedores, serve pra você “passar uma mensagem” aos outros que verão seu projeto no futuro.

Crie dentro do seu projeto o diretório que você deseja commitar e dentro deste diretório crie um arquivo chamado .gitkeep, deixando mais ou menos assim…

```
project-dir/
├── .git
├── other-dir
└── untracked-dir
    └── .gitkeep
```

Pronto, agora pode rodar os comandos `git add [seus arquivos]` e `git commit -m [mensagem de commit]`. Agora quando outro desenvolvedor se deparar com este arquivo irá saber do que se trata!