# Como forçar o git manter um diretório porém ignorando todos os arquivos que estão dentro dele?

Tags: git

Tenho uma determinada pasta e `logs` que é essencial para o funcionamento da minha aplicação. Gostaria de adicionar a mesma no meu repositório, pra quem replicar não quer que ficar criando a mesma quando fazer o `git clone`. Porém o detalhe é que os arquivos de log não deverão ir para o repositório, mas apenas a pasta.

Como fazer isso?

Comment: O Git aponta para arquivos, não diretórios, por isso não será possível adicionar um diretório/pasta vazio.

Comment: De certo modo sim, mas vide a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/256999/64969) em que o AR conseguiu "simular" o comportamento de diretório vazio pondo um arquivo oculto

Answer (score 3):

Para fazer isso no `git` basta adicionar um arquivo `.gitignore` dentro da pasta desejada e, em seguida, determinadas que todos os arquivos, exceto o `.gitignore` serão ignorados dentro dessa pasta.

Estrutura:

```
logs/
    .gitignore
```

Conteúdo do `.gitignore` que está dentro da pasta `logs`:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

Agora basta usar o comando `git add logs/`. Assim, a pasta `logs` será adicionada ao repositório, porém os arquivos de logs dessa pasta serão ignorados.

Eu costumo usar muito isso para pasta de uploads que precisam existir, porém não preciso dos arquivos que estão na mesma.

Comment: Engenhoso, porém devo dizer que não elegante. Eu já vi um _workaround_ desses no build de um projeto, ter a pasta sempre disponível para poder realizar o build em ambientes selvagens. Acho que o mais elegante para a necessidade de compartilhar um artefato seria gerar uma versão compactada com a tal pasta ou então ter um script "inicializador" que proveria essa estrutura, não através do controle de versão.

Answer (score 2):

Tem alguns pontos que discordo da [resposta do @WallaceMaxters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/256999/64969), assim como a [resposta do @egomesbrandao](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/257287/64969) também não me agradou como um todo. Vou dar uma explanada rápida de como funciona o esquema de pastas e arquivos de um repositório `git` e então evidenciar o porquê a afirmação do @egomesbrandao está correta e o porquê que a solução do @WallaceMaxters atende à pergunta.

Também não vou me ater a repositórios *bare*, a leitura do texto da resposta deve ser feita com isso em mente.

---

O `git` trabalha identificando arquivos, a partir da raiz do repositório (o local onde está situado o diretório `.git`). A identificação de um arquivo, no entanto, não é feito da tradicional forma dos sistemas de arquivos convencionais, mas é mais semelhante ao que a Amazon utiliza no S3.

Então, para o `.gitignore` da respostas do @WallaceMaxters, o `git` identifica esse arquivo pelo nome `/logs/.gitignore`. É tanto que mudanças no posicionamento/nome do arquivo o `git` sugere que você mudou o arquivo `x` para o arquivo `y`, independente da mudança ter sido só um renomear arquivo dentro do mesmo diretório, ou ter movido para outro diretório mantendo o nome, ou mesmo mudança de nome e de diretório.

Esse modo de identificação de arquivos implica que não existe o conceito de diretório (dentro da identificação interna do `git` pelo menos). Um dos impactos disso é que você não precisa se preocupar em manter os diretórios. Mover todos os arquivos de `/outer/inner/deep` para `/outer/inner` implica que, quando for dado o próximo `clone`, a pasta `/outer/inner/deep` não existirá. E você não precisou falar isso explicitamente.

A inexistência desse conceito de diretórios no `git` é a essência da resposta do @egomesbrandao, assim como é também a origem de um dos problemas originais da pergunta.

A solução proposta pelo @WallaceMaxters trata de se aproveitar da melhor maneira desse modo de operação do `git`. Internamente, pastas não existem. O que existe é identificador do arquivo com barras no meio. Em compensação, ao "extrair" esses arquivos e colocá-los no sistema de arquivos real, diretórios são criados para que o "nome com os diretórios" seja o mesmo do nome interno usado pelo `git`.

Meu ponto da discordância da resposta do @WallaceMaxters é: ao dar `git add logs`, você não adicionou o diretório (pois esse conceito não existe), mas sim TODO o conteúdo relevante dentro do diretório apontado. O `.gitignore`, no caso, é um arquivo oculto em sistemas de arquivo Unix, então a impressão dada é de que o diretório foi criado vazio. Para manter a estrutura do diretório, qualquer arquivo bastaria. Ocultos seriam melhores.

A solução do @WallaceMaxters aponta também para a questão de manutenção do conteúdo vazio da pasta `logs` no sistema de arquivos real (com a exceção do `.gitignore`, claro). Por isso que o arquivo escolhido para "povoar" a pasta foi o `.gitignore`, pois além de ser oculto (ideal para fazer o diretório existir) ele também impede o reconhecimento de novos arquivos.

---

Em muitos locais é comum usar um arquivo `.gitkeep` vazio. Diferentemente da resposta do @WallaceMaxters, o arquivo `.gitkeep` não tem interpretação especial, portanto não há porque colocar algo dentro dele. A diferença dessa alternativa é que o diretório onde ele se encontra não será imediatamente ignorado. Essa solução foi usada [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/275117/64969).

Comment: Concordo com sua resposta, foi uma explicação de com o a minha "gambiarra" funcionou. O Laravel usa isso no repositório original da aplicação.